# JQM - Date Picker, There is no mode by that name loaded / mode not given

Tags: jquery, jquery-mobile, datepicker

Following is my code, but still I receiving a message "There is no mode by that name loaded / mode not given". Why? Any help will be appreciated. Thanks.

**MY PAGE HEAD:**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.calbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="  http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.datebox.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.min.css" />
```

**MY PAGE BODY:**

```
<div id="indexPage" data-role="page">
   <input type="date" id="date_val" data-role="datebox" data-option="{'mode':'calbox'}">
</div>
```

P.S. I also change input field type "type='text'" and "type='date'" .. But result still same.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-latest.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="http://code.jquery.com/mobile/1.4.2/jquery.mobile-1.4.2.min.css">

<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.core.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.calbox.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="  http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.mode.datebox.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="http://dev.jtsage.com/cdn/datebox/latest/jqm-datebox.min.css" />


<div id="indexPage" data-role="page">
<input type="date" id="date_val" data-role="datebox" data-options='{"mode": "calbox", "useNewStyle":true}'>
</div>
```

Refer this fiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/aravinth/2752A/15/